# R: pulling only entries which are unique from a dataframe

Tags: r, unique

I'm looking to pull only those entries which occur **exactly** once within a dataframe. As an example:

> ```
> DataFrame1  
> Col1 Col2   
> ABC   5  
> DEF   6  
> DEF   7  
> HIJ   8
> ```

I would like to pull only:

> ```
> DataFrame2  
> ABC  
> HIJ
> ```

Where the uniqueness is determined only by Col1.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `unique` appart from being a tag in SO is also a function in R. Try `unique(dataFrame1[,1])`.

Comment: @Usobi Note that he wants the ones that are just once, not all the rows with the different name.

Comment: @Usobi, thanks for the response. Llopis is correct, I am looking to only return those observations which occur exactly one. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: awwww true true, sorry for the hasty and wrong response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit cumbersome, but this works:

```
x <- table(DataFrame1[, 1]) == 1
DataFrame2 <- na.omit(data.frame(ifelse(x, names(x),NA)))
```

Or more elegantly with sql:

```
library(sqldf)

DataFrame2 <- sqldf('select Col1 from DataFrame1 group by Col1 having count(Col1) = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ave` to create a vector of counts of the values in `col1` and subset based on that:

```
mydf[with(mydf, ave(Col1, Col1, FUN = length)) == "1", ]
#   Col1 Col2
# 1  ABC    5
# 4  HIJ    8
```

Or, similarly, with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, id := .N, by = Col1][id == 1]
#    Col1 Col2 id
# 1:  ABC    5  1
# 2:  HIJ    8  1
```

---

Duplicated also works, if you run it twice, once from each direction:

```
mydf[!(duplicated(mydf$Col1) | duplicated(mydf$Col1, fromLast=TRUE)), ]
#   Col1 Col2
# 1  ABC    5
# 4  HIJ    8
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `unique` help page there is a reference to `duplicate` that can help you (althought I haven't tested):

```
dup <- duplicate(DataFrame1$Col1)
DataFrame2 <- DataFrame1[!dup]
```

or with subset

```
DataFrame2 <- subset(DataFrame1, subset=!dup)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Unfortunately the above code also pulls out observations which have one or more observations, not only those with exactly one. Thanks again

Comment: @Mike, see my answer for how `duplicated` can still be used to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#If you want just the unique 
DataFrame1[which(table(DataFrame1[,"Col1"])==1),"Col1"]values.

#If you want the whole corresponding row.
DataFrame1[which(table(DataFrame1[,"Col1"])==1),]
```